# How to fill viewport with content from scrollable div when fixed div is hidden

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to fill the entire view-port of small displays with content from a scroll-able `div` after a fixed `div` is hidden. However, I am having trouble getting the scroll-able `div` to fill the entire view-port when I have made a fixed `div` hidden.

This is what I mean I have thus far:

HTML Template

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="side-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>#1</li>
        <li>#2</li>
        <li>#3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*Creating Fixed and Scrollable div*/

.side-bar{
  position: fixed;
}
.scrollable{
   position: relative;
}

/*Making fixed div disappear on small viewports*/

@media all and (max-width: 500px){
  .side-bar{
    display: none;  
  }
}
```

Currently, I am only using CSS and media queries to make this possible. How can I accomplish this?

As an illustration, I mean [something like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3#prerequisites) when testing the site's resposiveness.

Comment: I can see that both elements are wrapped in separate `.col-md-6` elements - hiding the element won't hide the parent element in this case. You could instead add classes on these "parent" elements and adjust their css similarly. I also don't feel like you would need `.side-bar` to be fixed, you could instead add `overflow: auto;` on the `.scrollable` element

Comment: I have noted that once the viewports change to less than 1000px then the side bar appears. I was able to achieve the same results using media queries as seen in the comment in @A Haworth's answer.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't removed class `side-bar`  from `col-md-6` but I have added scrollable to the class `row`. I have removed it from the class `col-md-6` `.scrollable` has `overflow: auto`, and this works as a charm only when I maintain `.side-bar`   within the media query. I have discarded the values of `.side-bar` in CSS. The small column is hidden when in smaller viewports and only visible in larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the side bar class on the containing div so the whole of that div disappears on a small device, otherwise that column may still be there even though its content is empty.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 side-bar”>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>#1</li>
        <li>#2</li>
        <li>#3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: True, the column remains from my example above. Adding `side-bar` on the first column div allows for the `scrollable` div to fill the entire view-port (small defined in the media query), but the `side-bar` is inconspicuously fixed within the overflowing content when the media is greater than 500px. This is not the desired output.

Comment: I have tried  this 
`
@media all and (min-width: 1000px){
    .sidebar{display: block}
}
`
in addition to the query above (having changed the `max-width` to `1000px` and it works. However, this range is too big. Any value below 1000px causes the `side-bar` to overlay the `scrollable`